# Late Binding C#4.0

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, c#-4.0, late-binding

I have multiple solution which contains multiple projects and with all combined gives my application. Following is the dependency in which my solutions are built:

```
Solution 1
Solution 2
Solution 3
...
Solution 14
Solution 15
```

Solution 14 uses some of the methods from Solution 3, so Solution 14 is kind of dependent on solution 3. So We refer Solution3 in Solution14.

Now we have extended functionality which requires me to add some calls in Solution3 which refers to the methods in Solution 14. How can I achieve the late binding for Solution3 features.

Can anybody guide me on this? I have being doing some search and found that Reflection could be useful, but  I am not sure. Am I approaching in the right direction?

Comment: `Solution 14 is kind of dependent on solution 14` I bet.

Comment: @vcsjones sorry for the mistake edited....!!!

Comment: I would look at refactoring the code instead of trying to circumvent the restriction against circular project references.

Comment: It's still very unclear. Can you not have one project which contains interfaces implemented which both solution 14 and solution 3 refer to? It's hard to give a very concrete suggestion when the question's pretty woolly. A short but complete example would really help. I think sorting out your dependency mess is likely to be a better long-term solution than late binding.

Comment: Refactoring at this point seems difficult as it would change a lot of stuff in our whole application.

Comment: Short example would be:
Main application uses different conditions for performing tests. SO we have Main application as Solution 14 and Interface containing diff test scenario as Solution3. Now we have to add feature that will trigger event when any conditions changes in Solution3. Now this Event trigger is callback client for Soluton14. So, this complex interdependence is occuring. This is not a single event capturing many more takes  place and so the entry point for all this has to be in Solution14.

Comment: I would agree with Jon, it sounds like you badly need to sort out your dependencies rather than trying to step around them.